# Indent the first paragraph of KOMA-Script's addmargin environment

Tags: indentation, koma-script

I use KOMA-Script's `addmargin` environment a lot when I need to shift the margins temporarily. It uses a list to do its job, however, and always sets `\itemindent` to `\z@`, meaning that the first paragraph will never be indented. That's likely the behavior that most people want most of the time, but I sometimes need it indented.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{addmargin}{2cm}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{addmargin}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have a solution below, which indents when the `indentfirst` package is loaded and not otherwise, but I'd be interested in other solutions that people have for this issue, especially if they're more configurable from instance to instance of the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution patches `addmargin` to check for the redefinition that `indentfirst` makes. If present, it sets `\itemindent` to `\parindent`. Otherwise, it observes the default behavior.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@addmargin}
{\setlength{\itemindent}{\z@}%
}
{\ifx\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
    \else
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\z@}%
    \fi}
{\typeout{Success patching}}{\typeout{Error patching}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{addmargin}{2cm}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{addmargin}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]